# How search the output only `-` in any DOM using PHP script?

Tags: php, css, dom, output

How search the output only `-` if any DOM as below?

1. `<p>-</p>`
2. `<p><span style="font-size: medium;">-</span></p>`
3. etc.

Currently I just use the codes as below to find this output `-` :

```
$input = `<p>-</p>`;
if($input == `<p>-</p>`):
   return true;
else:
   return false;
endif;
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: Since it's an exact match, your try is already sufficient. If the match is based on pattern, then you'll need RegEx.

Comment: Can you show me the details?

Comment: The condition is only if `-` existed...its means that no other characters involved.

Comment: Oops, apart from using RegEx, you can use `strpos($dom, '-')`

Comment: It should be noted that `p` element can't have a `div` child.

Comment: @Imran While making suggested edits to change [tag:bootstrap] to [tag:twitter-bootstrap] please understand that you need to try to fix all the issues with the post not just changing `bootstrap` to `twitter-bootstrap` everywhere and know that bootstrap is not owned by twitter anymore so while changing the tag is valid there is no need to change bootstrap to twitter bootstrap in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer would not work for special cases like if the tag attribute values contains `>-<` or if `-` is not wrapped within the tags:

```
$input = '<span title="A valid title >-<">Should NOT match</span>';
$input = '<span>Should match</span>-';
```

Instead you could use `strip_tags()`, which is not as efficient as `strpos()` but would work for all cases:

```
return (strip_tags($input) === '-');
```

Comment: This one,,,works as you mentioned - valid for all conditions.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$input = `<p>-</p>`;
$input = `<p><span style="font-size: medium;">-</span></p>`;
$input = `<p><div>-</div>`;
if(strpos($input, '>-<')):
   return true;
else:
   return false;
endif;
```

Comment: @ImranHamzah can be if(strpos($input, '>-</')): also to make sure